# What is wrong with this call to sed -i?

Tags: shell, find, osx

I have this line

```
find . -type f \( ! -name '*.plist' \) -and \( ! -name '*.mp4' \) -and \( ! -name '.DS*' \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/AAA/BBB/g'
```

my intention is from the current directory recursively change all occurrences of AAA to BBB in all files except those with the following extensions: .plist, .mp4 and .DS*

but I get the message

```
sed: 1: "./myDir/pro ...": invalid command code .
```

Comment: Are you on a mac or other BSD? I've noticed you have to include a suffix with `-i` on those. Try `-i.bak`

Comment: Mac. where do I put this -i.bak????

Comment: Replace the plain `-i` with it. `find [...] | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/AAA/BBB/g'`

Comment: ok, now I get another error: **sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence**

Comment: Looks like someone on SO had that problem, [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11287564/900873). Add `LANG=C` before the xargs: `find [...] | LANG=C xargs -0 [...]`

Comment: @Kevin Your comments would make a fine answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use this:

```
find . -type f \( ! -name '*.plist' \) -and \( ! -name '*.mp4' \) -and \( ! -name '.DS*' \) -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -w -e  's/AAA/BBB/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike GNU sed, the sed that ships with Mac OSX requires an argument to the `-i` option, specifying the backup suffix; to suppress the backup you have to pass an empty string (`''`). Therefore, sed was interpreting your `s/AAA/BBB/` as the backup suffix and taking your fist file name (`./myDir/pro ...`) as the command to execute. Of course, `.` is not a valid sed command, causing the error.  Keeping that in mind, the following will work:

```
find [...] | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/AAA/BBB/g'
```

Or, if you insist on suppressing the backup

```
find [...] | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/AAA/BBB/g'
```